Need help dealing with certain address scenarios in large cities and Google Places API
I have an issue with the London area using Google Places API and the endpoint for autocomplete. Why are we using autocomplete? Because our input is at time ambiguous. The background story is that we ask the customer for a specific location.
Anyway, imagine the following address "13 Manor Close" being searched using the Google Places Autocomplete API with the following code snippet.
import requests
import json

"""Autocomplete search parameters
"""
api = "XXXX"
address = "13 Manor Close"
lat = "51.5072"
long = "-0.1138486"
radius = 50000
language = "en"

"""Google Autocomplete payload
"""
payload = {
    "input": address,
    "locationRestriction": {
        "circle": {
        "center": {
            "latitude": lat,
            "longitude": long
        },
        "radius": radius
        }
    }
}

"""Get suggestions using autocomplete api
"""
response = requests.request(
    "POST",
    "https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:autocomplete",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "X-Goog-Api-Key": api},
    json=payload
)

response_dict = json.loads(response.text)

"""Iterate over returned suggestions
"""
for res in response_dict["suggestions"]:

    place_id = res["placePrediction"]["placeId"]

    """Use Google Places Detail lookup for the suggested place id
    """
    place = requests.request(
        "GET",
        f"https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places/{place_id}?key={api}",
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "X-Goog-Api-Key": api,
            "X-Goog-FieldMask": "*"
        }
    )
    
    place_dict = json.loads(place.text)
    print(place_dict)

If we query the autocomplete with locationRestriction and radius of 50,000m we get 5 results back.
  {
     "description":"13 Manor Close, Bengeo, Hertford"
  },
  {
     "description":"13 Manor Close, Hatching Green, Harpenden"
  },
  {
     "description":"13 Manor Close, London"
  },
  {
     "description":"13 Manor Close, Aveley, South Ockendon"
  },
  {
     "description":"13 Manor Close, Horley"
  }

Now here's the deal, the "13 Manor Close, London" returned in the above result in the postal code NW9, however the "13 Manor Close, London" also exists in SE28 and E17.
13 Manor Close, London SE28
https://www.google.com/maps/place/13+Manor+Cl,+London+SE28+8EY,+UK/@51.5088256,0.1190967,17z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x47d8af66c71b3579:0x9a72e5f3c90e4276!8m2!3d51.5088256!4d0.1216716!16s%2Fg%2F11cs94cnzx?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTEyNC4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D
13 Manor Close, London NW9
https://www.google.com/maps/place/13+Manor+Cl,+London+NW9+9HD,+UK/@51.58704,-0.2789375,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x4876115a17f0204f:0xf13ec4987368f8dd!8m2!3d51.58704!4d-0.2763626!16s%2Fg%2F11c23r9v_f?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTEyNC4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D
13 Manor Close, London E17
https://www.google.com/maps/place/13+Manor+Cl,+London+E17+5RT,+UK/@51.5964954,-0.0341318,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x48761dd91d4501ad:0x163048f90f55c230!8m2!3d51.5964954!4d-0.0315569!16s%2Fg%2F11c22cjwml?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTEyNC4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D
And unfortunately Google only return at most 5 results for the autocomplete. If we search specifically for "13 Manor Close, London" only NW9 and E27 is returned, but SE28 is not.
The only way to have them returned appears to be to pass the postal code in the search query for an example: 13 Manor Close SE28, but this is not something we can expect from the customer.
Have I managed to find a corner case, or is the London mapping this broken? Open for discussion, questions and suggestions how to deal with this scenario.

This is the same issue as https://issuetracker.google.com/73730686 although the solution is not necessarily forcing postal codes to be displayed when not requested. At any rate I would recommend subscribing to that issue report and adding your example/s for consideration.
To expand on what is there, consider that autocomplete predictions are aimed at helping a user find the one place they have in mind, so they would know (more or less) the address and would continue typing until they find a place the recognize. The issue here is a compound one:

only one "13 Manor Close, London" prediction can be offered (because if you show 2 or more of those, how would anyone know which one to pick?)
without additional input from the user, those places is London are "competing" for those 5 "top" positions with all the other "13 Manor Close" in the country
adding "London" to the input yields more predictions in London, but at the same time "close enough" predictions can also come up, e.g. "13 Manor Place, London"
adding the postal code to the "description" of predictions is a mostly independent issue from the issue of which ones get to show up in that "top 5".

